# SQL Query - how to create a sum based on grouped numbers

Tags: sql

I'd like to know how many messages (voicemailcount) were received for each rank (b.rankcode). Example Column 'b.rankcode' will have x number of people with a rank number who have gotten messages in 'voicemailcount'. If possible, I'd only like to see the voicemailcount and rankcode column.

```
select 
    count(*) as [voicemailcount], a.linkedusermailboxname, b.RankCode as 'Rank'  
from  
    UMCallDataRecord a 
join 
    UMADUserAccounts b on a.LinkedUserMailboxName = b.EmailAddress
where   
    a.CallType = 'callansweringvoicemessage' 
    and month(a.[date]) = month(GetDate()) - 1   -- change this per month   -1 = lastmonth
group by 
    a.linkedusermailboxname, b.rankcode 
order by 
    b.rankcode
```

TIA!

Comment: what is the result of your code, please give us more information.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we need to remove  "linkedusermailboxname" from the Select and from the GroupBy,  and remove the Join table and its On... >>

```
SELECT 
       b.rankcode AS 'Rank'
       ,Count(*)   AS [voicemailcount]

FROM   umcalldatarecord a

WHERE  a.calltype = 'callansweringvoicemessage'
       AND Month(a.[date]) = Month(Getdate()) - 1
-- change this per month   -1 = lastmonth

GROUP  BY b.rankcode
ORDER  BY b.rankcode
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you just need to reduce the number of columns that you group by

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*)   AS [voicemailcount]
  , ua.RankCode AS 'Rank'
FROM UMCallDataRecord AS cdr
JOIN UMADUserAccounts AS ua ON cdr.LinkedUserMailboxName = ua.EmailAddress
WHERE cdr.CallType = 'callansweringvoicemessage'
AND cdr.[date] >= dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, getDate())-1, 0) -- 1st day of last month
AND cdr.[date] < dateadd(month, datediff(month,0, getDate()), 0)    -- 1st day of current month
GROUP BY
    ua.rankcode
ORDER BY
    ua.rankcode
```

However I would like to propose a different way to define the date range because you could include results from any year in your current approach. The approach above will limit the results to everything from the previous month, and only the previous month. Note also I **do not** use `between` which just isn't great for date ranges.

I also concur with "Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)", use meaningful aliases, not aliases based on "sequence in a query"